# How to properly setup maven Spring Boot multi module project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

After some research try and fail, I am still not able to put my head around a clear way to do the following:

```
Project-All - "Ability to combine Module #1 & Module #2 and to run in dev (Test full solution)"
|
+ Module_1 - "Ability to run independently in dev (Different dev team)"
| - pom.xml
+ Module_2 - "Ability to run independentlyin dev (Different dev team)"
| - pom.xml
- pom.xml
```

I would like to build and run module_1 and module_2 separately, as well as assembled. After trying **Assembly Plugin for Maven** without significant success (Or over-complicated solution), I am now trying with **Spring Boot Plugin for Maven** which seems way simpler to use.

So would we have any recommendation on how to properly build such setup with **Spring Boot Plugin for Maven**?

Thanks

Comment: does one module depend somehow on another, or they are absolutely unrelated? and in which module you have main class with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: They are unrelated. The main class is in Module_1, but form a single app when assembled (e.g - Product Catalog and Admin panel)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can try :

In the main module POM you could use the maven release plugin like follows :

```
...
<packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
      <module>module1..</module>
      <module>module2..</module>
</modules>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <goals>install</goals>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you wish to build the submodules in such a way that they could run on its own :

your could use maven repckage goal in the module pom as follows:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

There is possibility providing the name of the main class in this configuration.
Checkout the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.1.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Thank you @SwapnilKhante
Going to try it and will let you know.